# While working with websockets can I pass in a header when sending a query string?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, websocket, http-headers

I'm working in xamarin using WebSocket4Net at the moment to connect to the GraphQL server. Now I'm trying to send a query string through the socket but I'm getting an error message saying not "authenticated as user". I'm getting this because I have to pass a token into the header however, I'm not doing it correctly yet.

I tried adding a custom header when first making the connection but that didn't seem to make a difference. Is there a way to set a header when I'm sending a query string?

I have it working in my GraphQL playground but I don't have it right in my code yet. [image: GraphQL Playground, right side is success data]

This is how I initialized the socket and you can see I tried adding in the custom header here but that hasn't made a difference.

```
public void Init(string Uri)
        {
            //Initialize the socket
            try
            {
                var cookies = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                var extension = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                extension.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x-token", AuthenticationAPI.CurrentToken.ToString()));
                sock = new WebSocket(Uri, "graphql-ws", customHeaderItems:extension);
                sock.Opened += (sender, data) => { OnConnect(data); };
                sock.MessageReceived += (sender, data) => { OnMessage(data); };
                sock.Closed += (sender, data) => { OnDisconnect(data); };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Init failed 
                sock = null;
                isConnected = false;
            }
        }
```

And then I try sending my query string here but get an error saying "Not Authenticated as User"

```
var variables = new Variables();
string entryDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", i.ActionDateTime);
var query = "mutation {logAction(episodeId: " + i.EpisodeId + ", listen: " + listenedTo + ") {episodeId listen position favorite entryDate}}"; //  + ", position: " + i.PlayerTime + ", favorite: " + i.Favorite.ToString().ToLower()
var payload = new WebSocketHelper.Payload(query, variables);
var JsonIn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new WebSocketCommunication("start", payload));
                                
DabSyncService.Instance.Send(JsonIn);
```

I've been trying to get this going for a week or so now if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using Websockets to query what looks to me as a GraphQL API ?

Comment: We want the instant communication. It's not really my decision.

Comment: But does the api you use fully support it ? It looks like you're getting HTTP like errors on your scenario

Comment: I believe so but I can double check this.

Comment: My serialization of classes was screwed up since it had a dash in it. Once I applied the attribute [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "x-token")] everything worked fine. I might delete this question though since it's just kind of a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My serialization of classes was screwed up since it had a dash in it. Once I applied the attribute [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "x-token")] everything worked fine.

https://code-examples.net/en/q/e11d59